# How to delete a file from internal memory before replacing it

Tags: android, file

I would like to delete an internal file at runtime. When I download from an external server, the old version of the file (with the same name) is replaced, however I am unable to read it. I think that I need to delete the previous file before downloading the new version. Here is an example of what I have tried so far:

```
try {
    FileOutputStream fos = getApplicationContext().openFileOutput("mytext.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    fos.write(getStringFromFile(pictosFile.getAbsolutePath()).getBytes());
    Log.e("mytextfile",""+getStringFromFile(pictosFile.getAbsolutePath()));
    progressDialog.cancel();
    fos.close();
} 
catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} 
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This allows me to save the file into internal memory, but I am unsure about how to delete the previous file before writing the new version.

Comment: File file = new File("somePath"); file.delete();

Comment: You do not need to delete an old file before overwriting it.  If you're not seeing the new version, something else went wrong (saved it to the wrong place, already had it open and didn't reopen it, etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to ensure that the file is overwritten, i.e. delete an old copy before saving a new version, you can use the `exists()` method for a file object. Here is an example showing how to delete an old version of an image file before writing a new file with the same name in a nested directory:

```
// Here TARGET_BASE_PATH is the path to the base folder
// where the file is to be stored

// 1 - Check that the file exists and delete if it does
File myDir = new File(TARGET_BASE_PATH);
// Create the nested directory structure if it does not exist (first write)
if(!myDir.exists())
    myDir.mkdirs();
String fname = "my_new_image.jpg";
File file = new File(myDir,fname);
// Delete the previous versions of the file if it exists
if(file.exists())
    file.delete();
String filename = file.toString();
BufferedOutputStream bos = null;

// 2 - Write the new version of the file to the same location
try{
    bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filename));
    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(width,height,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    bmp.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buf);
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,90,bos);
    bmp.recycle();
}
catch(FileNotFoundException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
finally{
    try{
        if(bos != null)
            bos.close();
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

You must also ensure that you have read / write access to memory, make sure that you ask the user for these permissions at run time and have the following in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```